# If-else VBA statement for auto-hiding rows in Excel2010

Tags: vba, excel, if-statement, excel-2010

I am trying to hide-auto hide some rows in my Excel 2010 spreadsheet, based on a value that is entered in a specific field. I am using data validation to set the minimum and maximum number between 0 and 50. If it is 0, then hide the next 3 rows, but if it is any other number, show the rows.

Below is the VBA code that works, except that I have to put it each possible number. Is there an IF Else statement I can use instead? If 0 then Hide, Else show the rows

```
If Target.Address(False, False) = "B45" Then

    Select Case Target.Value

        Case "0": Rows("46:48").Hidden = True

        Case "1": Rows("46:48").Hidden = False

        Case "2": Rows("460:48").Hidden = False

        Case "3": Rows("46:48").Hidden = False

        Case "4": Rows("46:48").Hidden = False

        Case "5": Rows("46:48").Hidden = False

        Case "6": Rows("46:48").Hidden = False

        Case "7": Rows("46:48").Hidden = False

        Case "8": Rows("46:48").Hidden = False

        Case "9": Rows("46:48").Hidden = False

        Case "10": Rows("46:48").Hidden = False

    End Select

    Else: Rows("46:48").Hidden = False

End If
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would you not just use:

```
Case Else
Rows("46:48").Hidden = False
```

?

This then says that anything that doesn't fit the first case (0) just defaults to this.

Sorry if I've misunderstood.

Comment: Thanks. I put that in there by mistake and forgot to take it out when I was trying some things out.

Comment: Ohhh I see what you're trying to achieve now, sorry, good answer by Ripster though.

Comment: oh. sorry. I changed it to the below, and it does not work:
If Target.Address(False, False) = "B57" Then
    Select Case Target.Value
        Case "0": Rows("58:60").Hidden = True
        Case Else
            Rows("58:60").Hidden = False
End If

Comment: Doesn't look like you've ended your Select statement? Try an End Select before your last End If.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using Select Case You can try:

```
If Target.Address(False, False) = "B45" Then
    If Target.Value > 0 And Target.Value <= 10 Then
        Rows("46:48").Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("46:48").Hidden = True
    End If
Else
    Rows("46:48").Hidden = False
End If
```

Comment: I'm having a new problem now...since I do this multiple times, the second if-else is affecting the auto-hide of the first


If Target.Address(False, False) = "B45" Then

    If Target.Value > 0 And Target.Value <= 50 Then

        Rows("46:48").Hidden = False

    Else

        Rows("46:48").Hidden = True

    End If

Else
    Rows("46:48").Hidden = False
End If

If Target.Address(False, False) = "B49" Then
    If Target.Value > 0 And Target.Value <= 50 Then
        Rows("50:52").Hidden = False
    Else
        Rows("50:52").Hidden = True
    End If
Else
    Rows("50:52").Hidden = False
End If